# NSIS Uninstallation problem Add Remove Program

Tags: nsis

I am creating the Installer Using NSIS,
The installation works without any problem, the uninstallation also works with UnInstaller.exe, but if i tried to uninstall the program from Add Remove Program, it gives the error i.e "Either program is already uninstalled or it is currepted, do you want to remove it from the list ?"

i am putting the UnInstallString also in the registry,  but still not working. please help.

Comment: Could you post the code that adds your registry entries?

Comment: Relevant Wiki entry: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you written all needed information in the registry? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954376.aspx, section 6. Support Add/Remove Programs Properly.

Comment: Thanks, i was not setting the UninstallString Properly, and that was the cause of not uninstalling from Add Remove Program.